How to Automatically Renew Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on All-Inkl DNS and Google Cloud VM (Ubuntu)?
I'm setting up an SSL certificate to verify ownership of my domain and ensure that the server is linked to the domain. I'm using Let's Encrypt for the certificate and want to ensure that the certificate renews automatically without manual intervention.
Currently, I manually add the _acme-challenge record and secret to the DNS server. My DNS provider is All-Inkl.
For the backend, I'm using a Google Cloud VM running Ubuntu.
How can I automate the renewal process for the SSL certificate without needing to update the DNS records manually? Any suggestions for configuring this with Let's Encrypt and All-Inkl would be greatly appreciated!

Why are you using the manual DNS resource record method? If you do not want to manually manage Let's Encrypt, delete what you have done and use supported automatic methods.

@JohnHanley have these supported automatic methods a name, so I can google it?

I recommend reading the documentation. There are hundreds of articles and blog posts on how to setup Let's Encrypt. This is a good site for articles: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu

FYI: the default setup is automatic certificate renewal. You went out of your way to setup manual DNS.

You can use Certbot and a cron job to Automatically Renew Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on All-Inkl DNS and Google Cloud VM (Ubuntu).
This sftp-gateway-gcp-3.0  article covers how to set up LetsEncrypt on Ubuntu It provides step-by-step instructions for the initial setup.
You need to Install Certbot and the Nginx plugin on the VM and Run Certbot to get the initial SSL certificate Test the certificate renewal process with sudo certbot renew.
Refer to this Digital ocean  tutorial  for more information
